# cross domain issue

Tags: javascript

There is a iframe in my page. This page is in domain A, the stuff in that iframe is belong to domain B. Is there any way I could get the source code of that page in that iframe?
This is a cross domain problem, the domain A and B are totally different. Also the domain B is third part domain, we can not do any changes on that.
For example, the stuff in iframe is google's homepage.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no *reliable* way to get the source of an `iframe` whose content is on a different domain that you do not control.

Comment: However you can call an AJAX on `Domain A` which gets the content from `Domain B` via HTTP and sends it back to `Domain A`. This is very longwinded, though!

Answer (score 0):

There are few techniques that can be applied here they are described in these writeups

http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/11/31/

http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes

Comment: I know google map actually makes this happen, so is there any tricky way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the iframe source
but you need to received the source with ajax call and set to the iframe.
I have done the same thing but i am facing different issue, i want to access the domain b function from the domain a.

```
{
Object.keys(db_obj).map(function(idx)
{
return(
    <div className="item">
    <iframe className="assignSrc" id={'iframe_'+idx} src={db_obj[idx].direct_url} width="720" height="520" onLoad={this.setImage.bind(this,db_obj[idx].image_embed_url+'/'+db_obj[idx].image_names)}  style={iframeHeightStyle}></iframe>
    </div>
    )

}.bind(this))
}
```

This is the react js code for given the iframe src with different url.May be it will help you.